# How to change the font of code block on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

I want to change the font of code block, and for this purpose I'm using [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) that loads javascript ( written by you ) every time a website loads.

Now, I'm changing the font through the following way:

```
var code = document.getElementsByTagName("code"); // through developer tools, I came to know that the code we see on the screen in enclosed in code tag. 

code[0].style.fontFamily = "Menlo"; // the default font is `Consolas`
```

It works fine when I view questions on stackoverflow.com, but when I try to edit a question, it doesn't give me preview as in the following picture:

[image]

So how can I come up with a solution?

Comment: Wrong place. its a question for SuperUser...

Comment: Since, it involves a bit of programming guide, I didn't post it on meta. As you guys are confused over it, I was so too. However, I've flagged this question for a moderator's attention to move it on a (more) related site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are prepared to add another extension, using [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) would make this easier. It injects CSS into matching pages, rather than injecting JavaScript with which you modify styles.

Then the CSS:

```
code {
  font-family: Menlo !important;
}
```

should be all you need.

Even using [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) the CSS approach will be easier: create an additional `<style>` element with the above CSS (I would keep the `!important` to save having to have a more specific selector to achieve sufficient priority in the CSS cascade.) This can be made easier with Tampmermonkey's support of `GM_` functions (it is a port of [Grasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/)): [`GM_addStyle`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle), thus your script would be simply:

```
GM_addStyle("code { font-family: Menlo !important; }");
```

Comment: Wrote this. Same problem. When I edit others' questions, the preview disappears. And one more problem, "Tags" in `Tag Area` are shown like pure text, no blue background and cross icon with them. :(

Comment: @ArslanAli Which approach (I list three) did you try? In any case you'll need to use Chromes developer tools to debug the application of the style (setting a obvious style, eg. `color: red !important;`) can be helpful to seeing where it is being applied. NB. if using your own DOM manipulation code it is very easy to modify too many elements. Finally: use those developer tools to see what HTML structure is used in the preview: you will likely need multiple selectors.

Comment: I've used each of your technique but the *same* problem occurs.