# Can I change the main font for SO? (Text readability)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface

- Can a user change the body font type from Sans to Serif for a SO site globally?
- Could it be a feature for SO site?
- *Added:* in other words, if the above is not adequate, or a bit too hard for a user to solve, then the proposal can be treated as: probably slightly change the SO's GUI design to achieve something like what is depicted on the screenshot below?

I know for example how to work-around this app-globally for Firefox, I can force all sites to display with some font, but I don't use it much because it messes up the look of many sites. There are probably some tricky plugins out there to solve this.

If I could simply choose the font, that looks more readable on my system, that would make sense for me. Now it is some Arial-like. And it is not what I would use for reading. 
Seriously? MO uses Serif and [English learning](http://english.stackexchange.com) is especially easy to read.
I am mostly on a Linux PC and use Firefox.

Edit:

It is clear that a user can try to tweak it on his browser.
But what I think, such feature would be probably a win-win concept for a user, and the content provider, who also invests time to make it all look nice. Possibility to edit own settings in profile keeps the whole scheme cleaner, in first time for the user, who does not know anything about system fonts, but want to get more readable picture. And there is no need to develop something for something obvious.

Anyway I am not sure how many people play with browser setup and it is somewhat not intuitive for me how this all interacts with page's styles.

So what I make **to reduce eye strain** is choose Serif font and in my case on Linux it would be probably "Liberation Serif" for body and "Courier 10 pitch" for Monospaced (code). It looks like this screenshot:

[image]

It seems like I achieve what I want, but it is *not only* the font, also interline spacing and word spacing and relative size of different styles which is important.
Also in this case the font is of a bit too light color, which is not the case for Sans-serif, (the latter would look not too sharp). I would also want to setup relative size which I cannot do for SO.
`Liberation` font has initially smaller glyph size, which means slightly more interline spacing which is good for eyes. Other fonts are not, they have different metrics and that leads to different interline spacing, unless the spacing is controllable on the client GUI.

From my publishing experience, I orient myself on following principle when I decide about readability. It is not fair to compare with screen fonts, but generally it applies all the same.

[image]

As for topic titles, it is better to use other font/color, just to outline logical structures.
For monospaced (code part), Courier seems to me to be still better than even the top-notch Windows' "Consolas".

Comment: This is probably something you should set in your browser.

Comment: Can you clarify your post to make it an explicit [tag:feature-request]? As it is, it can also be interpreted as a "local user problem" (and thus better asked on askubuntu.com or Super User. Also check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253697/2564301

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, made it. It is more about the global site look. And default Browser setup does not seem to provide simple universal solution. Anyway if I were a total noob, I couldn't figure it out either way.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes that is what I am trying to do. But the question has also other dimension, f.e. see my comments on Hans' answer.

Comment: But initial SO's font change could hurt if one has some dependency on the default font's setup. It could be true if one already uses some Plugin with hard-coded style tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a browser extension you can get called Stylish that will let you change many aspects about websites you visit including the font.

You can check it out at https://userstyles.org/ for more information.

Comment: Didn't try it but I would look into it. Hope this'll be worth the effort, since I don't know CSS and I should probably to configure it.

Comment: @MikhailV I have used this to change all the font setting for google chat services

Comment: I've gone through brief infos and related questions, something still is not clear, for example important for me would be possibility to set the bitmap texture as background to achieve good results, but I am not even sure if it is possible with this plugin. If not possible then it is not the best ever way. But I may be wrong, haven't done more close inspection. Would be nice to have some mini wiki of its possibilities with 1:1 screenshots.

Comment: @MikhailV My knowledge of the plugin is not as deep as I would like and I mainly use it for simple font changes.

Comment: This happens to be a perfect solution. I am able to tweak almost everything, and yes, I can also set the bitmap for background. When I master this plugin, I'll post the results.

Comment: @MikhailV I am looking forward to seeing what you create.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283843/has-somebody-already-created-a-user-style-of-a-more-readable-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 8):

Font mapping for the SO sites on Windows is quite atrocious.  Just [add your own substitution font](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939628.aspx) so the OS X-centric "Helvetica Neue" gets mapped to a font that is less an assault to the eyes than Arial.

Fire up Regedit.exe and navigate to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`.
Right-click the key > New > String value.  Name it "Helvetica Neue".  Set the value to a font you like; I use "Segoe UI".  Big, big difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am on Linux most of the time, though.

Comment: On windows, I think it was Perpetua or something like this that looked excellent for text.

Comment: @MikhailV: but surely Linux offers more user control over browsers than Windows or OS X?

Comment: The obvious Google query is "Linux font substitution", top hit is a superuser question.

Comment: @Jongware Despite I am programmer, I never dig much into browsers, I know only that the font list is in HTML tag and the first match is taken from the system to render it. As it is for most users, I believe.

Comment: yes, exactly on Windows 7 "Perpetua" - Serif, "Calibri" - Sans are well screen optimised. And "Georgia" is on most Windows I believe.

Comment: To be honest, my opinion is: it would be good then if Liberation (Linux) and Perpetua (Win) is the default for body, and Courier is for the code. If we speak only about less eye strain. Reading a lot of text on SO is what I do and I cannot say for "design". Anything far from this scheme, even with a very good Sans-serif for the body, is not "prescribed by the doctor" so to say.