# Why is everything bold now?

Tags: bug, design

**Has something changed? To me this looks not normal (Latest FF, Win 10 Creators Update):**

[image: Bold]

**While Google Chrome is fine (Not as bold as above screenshot):**

[image: Normal]

Comment: Not reproducing this.  Try flushing your cache and seeing if it persists?

Comment: Developer consoles in both browsers report the same font-weight (400) for me.  Perhaps it's a FF only rendering?  It does appear slightly darker in FF to my eye, but maybe I'm just seeing things.

Comment: I see this too. Appears to be a recent change in FF.

Comment: @Shog9 I have voted to close, because it was after pc restart not reproduceable now. (Only strange thing was, I got an purple logoff screen, you too?) Maybe I was to fast.

Comment: I opened up Firefox Developer Edition and did notice a strange boldness to it.  Smells like a Firefox problem, but I wonder if other browsers (not named Chrome) are impacted too.

Comment: **I was really hoping all your text would be in bold on this question.** Unable to reproduce this though. w7, chrome.

Comment: @TravisJ fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Dammit @TravisJ, that was just going to be one for the lolz.  Now look what you've done. :P

Comment: Seems OK to me... FF 52.1.2 (32-bit).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315399/17034